# Sending a string/result from JS to HTML-page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working on a simple rock, paper, scissors game of HTML + JS.

Here are the full codes (CSS, JS, HTML): http://jsfiddle.net/fJw4R/
(too long to past here I thought). Here you can see it with pictures: http://shinebrightmedia.se/rps/rockpaperscissors.html

As you can see, the .math-module works, and when you choose rock, paper or scissor the computer randomizes a choice.

However, I now would like to have a textstring underneath the computer/monitor, and I'm wondering what the easiest way to do that. I want it to either say YOU WIN! or YOU LOSE!

I started on a function looking like this:

```
function theWinnerIs(userChoice, computerChoice) {

    if (userChoice === computerChoice ) {
        return 'No winner, it is a draw';
    }

    if ((userChoice === 'rock') && (computerChoice === 'scissor')) {
        return 'human';
    }
    if ((userChoice === 'rock') && (computerChoice === 'paper')) {
        return 'computer';
    }

    if ((userChoice === 'paper') && (computerChoice === 'scissor')) {
        return 'computer';
    }
    if ((userChoice === 'paper') && (computerChoice === 'rock')) {
        return 'human';
    }

    if ((userChoice === 'scissor') && (computerChoice === 'rock')) {
        return 'computer';
    }
    if ((userChoice === 'scissor') && (computerChoice === 'paper')) {
        return 'human';
    }

}
```

What is the easiest way to send the return to the index-file? ie. YOU WIN! or YOU LOSE!

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to use this block of `if`s - here's very compact alternative:

```
var choices = { rock: -1, paper: 0, scissors: 1 };
var score   = choices[userChoice] - choices[computerChoice];
score       = score - (score/2|0) * 3;
```

... which will give you `-1` if user loses the round, `1` if they win, `0` in case of draw.

Now you can just send the output to any prepared container by filling its innerHTML property:

```
var results = {
  '-1': 'YOU LOSE',
   '1': 'YOU WIN',
   '0': 'IT\'S A DRAW'   
};
var resultContainer = document.getElementById('result');
resultContainer.innerHTML = results[score];
```

Here's [**a small demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/HLR63/) to illustrate both those concepts.

Comment: Hi! Thanks alot for your help, that code snippet looks really neat! I tried applying it, but the game stops working afterwards. I tried to implement this in the .html file: <p id="result"></p> inside a div. Is this wrong?

Comment: 'but the game stops working afterwards' - what's the console output?

Comment: It just stops working, nothing happens when I press any icon. With console output do you mean running the code on JSlint?

Comment: JSLint certainly won't hurt, but I actually meant the browser's console (usually opened when you press `F12`).

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you would like to display some text depending on the outcome of your "theWinnerIs" method. I would suggest you create a div on your page and set its content with JavaScript. There are numerous ways to accomplish your goal, however.

So you want to add a div to your page, something like `<div id="output"></div>`. You can then update the text here with the following

```
var outputElement = document.getElementById("output");
outputElement.innerHTML = theWinnerIs(userChoice, computerChoice);
```

Here's an [updated version](http://jsfiddle.net/Ninjakannon/fJw4R/3/) of your code for perspective, though raina77ow's solution is much nicer.